# Opening popups from AS3 using ExternalInterface in Safari

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, safari, popup, externalinterface

I'm using this code to open a popup

```
ExternalInterface.call("function () { window.open('" + url + "','" + title + "','" + options + "'); }");
```

*for JavaScript people*: calling `ExternalInterface.call(string);` from flash player lets the browser do `eval(string)();`

as this call is within a click handler, it even works perfectly with Firefox and IE, for Opera it lets you open the popup manually.
But in Safari, it is always blocked **silently**. Anyone have an idea how circumvent this?

thanks

back2dos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this, and as far as I could tell there was no real solution... the only workaround I could find was essentially checking if window.open works, and if it doesn't use navigateToURL instead... I just found this link that explains this much better:
http://www.asserttrue.com/articles/2007/08/22/workaround-for-safari-blocking-flash-initiated-pop-ups

Comment: from the link, this looks quite useful:
http://www.asserttrue.com/articles/2009/04/29/navigatetowindow-project-added-to-github

Comment: thanks for the link. it does quite much what I am doing, but it's nicely wrapped ... :)

Comment: ok, nothing seems to really work ... but this solution at least has a nice fallback integrated, so i guess, this is the best answer i could get ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be creating your function inside of AS3. That's probably one of the reasons you are getting bad behavior.

You should create your function in the HTML or JS files and call it with EI, and pass the arguments you need.

Comment: do you think, that solves the problem? the javascript is definitely executed. i'll give it a try, but i'm very sceptical

Comment: Even if it doesn't solve the problem, it's a good habit.

But yes, I think that it is plausible that is the issue.